# Setting a while loop that validates multiple input?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I need help validating input. I have a program that works with student grades based off user input. if someone enters grades below 0 or over 100 I want this loop to restart. Here is what I have so far:

```
double scores[] = new double[size];

for (int i = 0;i<= scores.length-1;i++)
{
    System.out.print("\n\nScore number " + (i+1) + ": ");
    scores[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Here are your scores: " + Arrays.toString(scores));
```

I'm confused on how to implement invalid checker. I know it has something to do with a while loop. such as while a value is 0, and if someone enters invalid answer it will change from 0. But not sure how exactly I should do this, or if theres a better way
Any help appreciated. thanks

Comment: Instead of re-iterating the loop, wouldn't it be better if you just ask the user to re-enter the value of the score which has been entered wrong?

Comment: Do you want the loop to restart, or do you want the user to enter new input?  If the loop restarts with the same input, won't it do so infinitely?

Comment: @Mike Do you agree with what I've answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a nested while loop and conditional statement for this:

```
        for (int i = 0;i< scores.length;i++){
            while(true){
                System.out.print("\n\nScore number " + (i+1) + ": ");
                int score = sc.nextInt();
                if(score >= 0 && score <=100){
                    scores[i] = score;
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Error: score entered is outside allowable range");
                    System.out.println("Please try again");
                    continue;
                }                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ask the user to re-enter the value of the score which has been entered wrong.

```
double scores[] = new double[size];
for (int i = 0; i<= scores.length-1; i++)
{
    System.out.print("\n\nScore number " + (i+1) + ": ");
    scores[i] = sc.nextInt();
    if(scores[i] < 0 || scores[i] > 100) {
        i -= 1;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having one lesser loop does'nt mean improved in efficiency in your case. This coding style is questionable when you force a for-loop to perform like a while loop. Just think about the flexibility of your code when you need to add more codes. You will face problems due to the hard coded nature of variable i and use of `continue`. Your program doesn't flow naturally and elegantly, but instead, was hard coded to meet a very specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused on how to implement invalid checker. I know it has something to do with a while loop.

`do-while` loop is preferred in input validation because it allows input to be received first, then check if it passes the requirement. If input is invalid, repeat.

```
for(int i=0; i<scores.length; i++){
    do{
        System.out.print("\n\nScore number " + (i+1) + ": ");
        input = sc.nextInt();
    }while(input < 0 || input > 100);

    scores[i] = input;
}
```

The for-loop and do-while loop serve different purpose. Hence, do not be confused by the

**- for-loop** which is only responsible to receive multiple inputs for the array and the

**- while loop** which is only responsible for validating every single input.

Comment: Following your changes, the complexity increases, which is not preferable.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. Both the time and space complexity reamains even though I used 2 loops here.

Comment: Okay yeah, I see what you are trying to convey.